# Generated mp3 file does not play in IOS on either Safari, Chrome or Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ios, safari, mp3

I am recording using MediaRecorder in JQuery which is now supported in Safari. It has to be enabled.

This works.

The below code snipped is taking the recording. Grabbing the data and then posting it through to a PHP file which is simply writing a file and saving as an mp3.

```
recordButton.addEventListener("click", toggleRecording);


function toggleRecording() {
    if (recorder && recorder.state == "recording") {
        recorder.stop();
        gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
        $("#record").html('Record');
    } else {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true
        }).then(function(stream) {
            gumStream = stream;
            const chunks = [];
            recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
                chunks.push(e.data);
                const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/mpeg' }); 

                var reader = new window.FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                     base64data = reader.result;
                     mp3 = reader.result.replace('data:audio/mpeg;base64,',''); 

                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('b',mp3);
                    fd.append('c',$("#company").val());
                    fd.append('d',$("#device").val());

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/include/concierge/storeBlob.php',
                        data: fd,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        $("#message-box").addClass("active-flyin");
                        $("#menu-hider").addClass("menu-hider-active flyin-hider");
                        $("#returnid").val(data);
                    });
                }
            };
            recorder.start();
            $("#record").html('Stop');
        });
    }
}
```

It is posted to a PHP file where it is simply doing....

```
file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($blob));
```

I am then calling the file like .....

```
<audio controls id='mess-".$d->id."' preload='none'>
    <source src='".returnURI($d->filename)."' type='audio/mpeg'>
    This text displays if the audio tag isn't supported.
</audio>
```

Where the src is https://my.digitalconciergehub.co.uk/tmp/company/1/walkietalkie/200103135121audio.mp3

In Android, windows desktop browsers this all works fine and the above link works.

It will not work on IOS and Mac Safari. I am guessing it is to do with the format of the mp3?